# Ruby on Rails custom checkbox label

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 <%= f.check_box :google_serch,  {}, "true", "false"  %>
```

I am using Rails Bootstrap Forms gem. How can I make label for this checkbox to be
"Include Google search results" without using f.label ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<strong>Include Google search results</strong>` right above the check-box in the form.

Comment: But then I will have 2 labels on the page

Comment: I mean't to replace the `f.label` with the strong tags.

Comment: Yes, but '<%= f.check_box :google_serch,  {}, "true", "false"  %>' also generates label which is "Google search" and  I do not know how to customise this label

Comment: Did you try `label: false` on the checkbox?

Comment: label: false did not change anything